# setting up a script to rotate scren Lenovo Yoga Thinkpad S1

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, thinkpad, rotate-monitor

I am trying to set up a Lenovo Yoga Thinkpad S1 to rotate the screen with the touch of a button but I am having a little trouble with the script that actually does the work.

I have found the scripts that does everything I need [here.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2193327)

The script that is giving me trouble is the first tone of post number 6.
The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script rotates screen 90deg on every run, and also rotates touchscreen and wacom input.
# In modes other than normal, touchpad is deactivated.

current_orientation(){
    xrandr|grep " connected" |awk '{print $4}'
}
#orientation=`current_orientation`
case $( current_orientation ) in
    "(normal" )
        xrandr -o left
        xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen stylus" rotate ccw
        xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen eraser" rotate ccw
        synclient TouchpadOff=1
        xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axes Swap" "1"
        xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 1 0
        onboard &
        ;;
"inverted" )
    xrandr -o right

    xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen stylus" rotate cw
    xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen eraser" rotate cw
    xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axes Swap" "1"
    xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 0 1
    ;;
"right" )
    xrandr -o normal
    xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen stylus" rotate none
    xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen eraser" rotate none
    synclient TouchpadOff=0
    xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axes Swap" "0"
    xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 0 0
    killall onboard
    ;;
"left" )
    xrandr -o inverted
    xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen stylus" rotate half
    xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen eraser" rotate half
    xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axes Swap" "0"
    xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 1 1
    ;;
* )
    synclient TouchpadOff=0
    echo "c est autre chose"
    current_orientation
    #echo $orientation
        ;;
esac
```

When I run the script from the button nothing happens. (button is configured to call the script from keyboard shortcuts). I have set the script to execute with chmod +x. However, when I run the script from the command line I get "c est autre chose". As this is is in the script I can see that the script is working?? - I guess. But it does not rotate the screen at all. Or turn off touchpad.

This script works for others with the same model of computer using different flavors of Ubuntu. I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. I have already set up the palm rejection script also found in post number 6 and it is working fine.

I would ask on the forum where I found the script but registration is temporarily closed.

Comment: Check the output of `xrandr|grep " connected"` - I think you will need to change the line to xrandr|grep " connected" |awk '{print $5}'

Comment: xrandr|grep " connected" responds with:eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 276mm x 156mm
But changing the script with xrandr|grep " connected" |awk '{print $5}' did the trick! Script works great! How did you know that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the script to `xrandr|grep " connected" |awk '{print $5}'` as [Charles suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516806/setting-up-a-script-to-rotate-scren-lenovo-yoga-thinkpad-s1/516819#comment701323_516806).

Comment: @user255190 I examined the output of the xrander command, and noticed that the phases you are looking for are in the 5th output place rather than the 4th output place.  I would suggest you edit your answer above, and say something about that which would satisy Mew as to why this change worked, mentioning that perhaps the output of xrander has changed since the script was first written.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change synclient touchpadoff=0 to synclient touchpadon=1 and at right" styles rotate half and erase" rotate half.

and it might work fine this way.