# Yoga S1 Automatic Screen Rotation?

Tags: 14.04, touchscreen

Is there any way to get Ubuntu 14.04 to recognize the accelerometer built into the thinkpad yoga S1?

Magick-Rotation seems to have quit a few years ago, and I couldn't find anything else besides manual scripts. Any advice?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/516806/setting-up-a-script-to-rotate-scren-lenovo-yoga-thinkpad-s1